# Getting Member Data From WhishList Member Plugin on Register

Tags: php, wordpress

I contacted WLM tech support and asked:

> "I'm using the WishList Member API is there a way I could figure out if a new member has been added to Wishlist? I'd like to capture the newest member's name and email address and then use that it in my plugin."

They responded with:

> "You can use wishlistmember_shoppingcart_register (action).
>
> Called when a new member is signed-up via one of the shopping cart integrations. Information about the registration can be found in the $_POST variable."

I'm wondering how to do this... should I use an action?

```
add_action('wishlistmember_shoppingcart_register', 'get_member_info'));

function get_member_info(){
    //get $_POST
   // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Also, should I use this code in a plugin and add the shortcode to the Wordpress page with the form on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by moving my plugin shortcode to the after registration page and then capturing the data I wanted using the Wish List Member shortcodes.

```
function mgc_init(){

 $firstname = ' ';
 $lastname = ' ';
 $email = ' ';

if ( shortcode_exists( 'wlm_firstname' ) ) {

    // The [wlm_firstname] short code exists.
    $var = do_shortcode( '[wlm_firstname]' );

    $var = trim($var);

    if(!empty($var)){

        //set global var
        $firstname = $var;

        mgc_print($firstname);
    }
  }
}
add_shortcode('mgc_int','mgc_init'); //put this shortcode [mgc_int] on after registration page in Wordpress
```